DateTime vs Date in Excel and power APPS
I have a PowerBI dashboard with comments in one tab comming from a list on an Excel file. I´m developing an app with power apps (which is inserted into powerbi) that should take certain data from the item selected in a visualization and allow me to write a comment that will be inserted in the excel file and therefore visible back in the PoweBI dasboard.
Everithing works fine, but the I cannot propperly manage the format of a field with the date of the registry.
In powerApps the type of the field "date" is DateTime and therefore shows boxes for the hours an minutes, which I want to delete. I´ve changed the format in the excel of origing in different ways and it does not work. I cannot simply try to put the date as a text with te proper format as the input will come from a filed that is a date.
In sumary, nomater what I do I cannot change the format of the filed in PowerApps and get rid of the hours and minutes.
Any other ideas how to do it?
